# Is this a good way to lock a loop on 60 loops per second?

Tags: c++, algorithm, loops, timer

I have a game with [Bullet Physics](http://bulletphysics.org/Bullet/BulletFull/classbtRigidBody.html) as the physics engine, the game is online multiplayer so I though to try the [Source Engine approach](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Source_Multiplayer_Networking) to deal with physics sync over the net. So in the client I use [GLFW](http://www.glfw.org/) so the fps limit is working there by default. (At least I think it's because GLFW). But in the server side there is no graphics libraries so I need to "lock" the loop which simulating the world and stepping the physics engine to 60 "ticks" per second.

Is this the right way to lock a loop to run 60 times a second? (A.K.A 60 "fps").

```
void World::Run()
{
    m_IsRunning = true;

    long limit = (1 / 60.0f) * 1000;
    long previous = milliseconds_now();

    while (m_IsRunning)
    {
        long start = milliseconds_now();
        long deltaTime = start - previous;
        previous = start;

        std::cout << m_Objects[0]->GetObjectState().position[1] << std::endl;

        m_DynamicsWorld->stepSimulation(1 / 60.0f, 10);

        long end = milliseconds_now();
        long dt = end - start;

        if (dt < limit)
        {
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(limit - dt));
        }
    }
}
```

Is it ok to use **std::thread** for this task?

Is this way is efficient enough?

Will the physics simulation will be steped 60 times a second?

P.S

The `milliseconds_now()` looks like this:

```
long long milliseconds_now()
{
    static LARGE_INTEGER s_frequency;
    static BOOL s_use_qpc = QueryPerformanceFrequency(&s_frequency);
    if (s_use_qpc) {
        LARGE_INTEGER now;
        QueryPerformanceCounter(&now);
        return (1000LL * now.QuadPart) / s_frequency.QuadPart;
    }
    else {
        return GetTickCount();
    }
}
```

Taken from: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/26759/best-way-to-get-elapsed-time-in-miliseconds-in-windows

Comment: If you are using C++11 already, you should use a clock from [<chrono>](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/chrono) library instead of Windows-specific timers.

Comment: Use unsigned long for your time variables to avoid overflow issues.

Comment: @Erbureth But is the standard library efficient enough for this task?

Comment: This largely appears to be a code review, which would be better suited on [codereview.se]. Although I'm curious as to why you posted this to [so] instead of [gamedev.se].

Comment: @UnTraDe definitely not worse than `GetTickCount`

Comment: @UnTraDe Anyway, for measuring 60 FPS, the standard library is indeed good enough.

Comment: @Erbureth But the functions there returning minimume scale of seconds and I need a scale of milliseconds.

Comment: @UnTraDe According to the documentation, those standard functions are capable of operating with nanoseconds

Comment: @UnTraDe see http://ideone.com/K7BIHk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to limit the rendering to a maximum FPS of 60, it is very simple :

Each frame, just check if the game is running too fast, if so just wait, for example:

```
while ( timeLimitedLoop )
{
    float framedelta = ( timeNow - timeLast )
    timeLast = timeNow;

    for each ( ObjectOrCalculation myObjectOrCalculation in allItemsToProcess )
    {
        myObjectOrCalculation->processThisIn60thOfSecond(framedelta);
    }

    render(); // if display needed
}
```

Please note that if vertical sync is enabled, rendering will already be limited to the frequency of your vertical refresh, perhaps 50 or 60 Hz).

If, however, you wish the logic locked at 60fps, that's different matter: you will have to segregate your display and logic code in such a way that the logic runs at a maximum of 60 fps, and modify the code so that you can have a fixed time-interval loop and a variable time-interval loop (as above).  Good sources to look at are "fixed timestep" and "variable timestep" ( [Link 1](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/1589/fixed-time-step-vs-variable-time-step) [Link 2](http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/fix-your-timestep/) and the old trusty Google search).

**Note on your code:**
Because you are using a sleep for the whole duration of the 1/60th of a second - already elapsed time you can miss the correct timing easily, change the sleep to a loop running as follows:

instead of

```
if (dt < limit)
        {
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(limit - dt));
        }
```

change to

```
while(dt < limit)
        {
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(limit - (dt/10.0)));
            // or 100.0 or whatever fine-grained step you desire
        }
```

Hope this helps, however let me know if you need more info:)

Comment: Unsigned time variables should be used when computing delta values. Just an extra thing to be careful.

Comment: true forgot to unsign it...that's what I get for writing it afresh rather than copy and pasting from my code:)

Comment: It was meant to remind you so that you add it as a notice for the op. The important part is the time variables not the delta one.

Comment: Personally I didn't say unsigned float specifically. Just that unsigned values should be used on the time variables. Unsigned long or something should do.